# Restrict osCommerce shopping cart to only allow one item 

Tags: php, oscommerce

I don't want customers to add more than one unique item in their basket in osCommerce. I know that for the same product the multiple count can be restricted by setting:

> Admin → Configuration → Maximum values → Product Quantities In Shopping Cart = 1.

But that's for the same product to restrict multiple quantities.

I want one and only one product at a time in the cart. If the customer buys "A" first and then buys "B", there should only be "B" in the cart.

Comment: What version are you running?

Answer (score -1):

if you look at catalog/application_top.php around line 390 you may find a bit of code that looks like:

```
 // customer adds a product from the products page
      case 'add_product' :    if (isset($HTTP_POST_VARS['products_id']) && is_numeric($HTTP_POST_VARS['products_id'])) {
                                $cart->add_cart($HTTP_POST_VARS['products_id'], $cart->get_quantity(tep_get_uprid($HTTP_POST_VARS['products_id'], $HTTP_POST_VARS['id']))+1, $HTTP_POST_VARS['id']);
```

Amend the first line of that to something like:

```
  case 'add_product' :    if (isset($HTTP_POST_VARS['products_id']) && is_numeric($HTTP_POST_VARS['products_id']) && $cart->count_contents() < 1) {
```

That'll stop more than 1 being added from the product pages - you will also have to cover case 'buy_now' in teh same file if it is in use and also edit the shopping_cart.php file to remove the ability for customer to order multiple quantities of the single product you are allowing.

the above is based on osC 2.2